# SMS Problem - Moto G update 4.4.4

Tags: sms, 4.4-kitkat

A problem appeared in my Moto G after the update to 4.4.4. Hangout app stop work with SMS. Beside that I can't activate the factory SMS app.
I tried to install some alternative SMS apps and all of them crash when I try to send some message.

[image: Can't activate the factory SMS app]

If I send a normal Hangout everything works flawlessly, but if I select the SMS functionality the app crashes.

I check the Logcat and this exception is raised:

```
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): android.telephony.CallISmsApp$NeedRetryException: getService ISmsApp is null!
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at android.telephony.CallISmsApp.getISmsApp(CallISmsApp.java:63)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at android.telephony.CallISmsApp.calculateLength(CallISmsApp.java:133)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at android.telephony.SmsMessage.calculateLength(SmsMessage.java:302)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at com.google.android.apps.babel.views.ComposeMessageView.a(SourceFile:82)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at com.google.android.apps.babel.views.ag.run(SourceFile:190)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-14 14:09:29.970: E/CallISmsApp(11124): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I never developed something using SMS but it seems the service is inactive. That means the problem is with my SMS functionality of the device, not the Hangout. And before 4.4.4 all was well!

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see this issue quite frequently.  Hangouts will crash if you disable stock Messaging app, but you can't re-enable the Messaging app if you've disabled it before upgrading the OS.

In order to resolve you need to go into Settings -> Apps, tap the three-dot menu button, and select the "Reset app preferences" option:
[image: Screenshot]

This re-enables all previously disabled apps, including the ones you couldn't re-enable before.  Hangouts should also stop crashing now.